# NestJs Typeorm - Entity mapped to oracle view giving error "ORA-32575: Explicit column default is not supported for modifying views"

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to do insert on oracle view (trigger on view will insert on actual table)using nestjs typeorm, if I don't pass firstname or lastname then I am getting error "ORA-32575: Explicit column default is not supported for modifying views"

I can handle this null values through subscriber but is there any other way to tell typeorm simply skip null column from query ?

Interesting thing is if array of entities are passed to save/insert, then query automatically sets null values but for single entity it tries to set "default" for missing values

```
INSERT INTO \"PD_USER_VIEW\"(\"FIRSTNAME\", \"LASTNAME\", \"USERID\") VALUES (:1, DEFAULT, :2) -- PARAMETERS: [\"pravin4\",\"4\"]
```

```
create or replace view pd_user_view 
as (select
userid, 
firstname, 
lastname,
from pd_user)

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER TR_pd_user_view_INSERT
INSTEAD OF INSERT
ON pd_user_view
REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

insert into pd_user(userid, firstname, lastname) values (:new.userid, :new.firstname,:new.lastname);

END TR_pd_user_view_INSERT;
```

````
@Entity({ name: 'pd_user_view' }) 
export class PdUserView { 
 
 @Column({ name: 'FIRSTNAME' }) 
 firstname: string 
 
 @Column({ name: 'LASTNAME' }) 
 lastname: string 
 
 @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'USERID' }) 
 userid: string 
 
}```
````

Comment: Use implicit default - omitting column-value pair.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by implicit default ? Do you mean adding "default : null" in @Column ?

Comment: By implicit default, it means that don't impromptu set values for default columns. By "default: null" in the column, you are setting an explicit default. Yes, use default values as `default` and not `null`. It does not recognize null values.

Comment: I already tried putting "default : null" in column , but since typeorm entity is mapped to view , it always set value as "DEFAULT"

Comment: Is it giving expected results on not putting `default: null` on the column?

Comment: Even if I put "default : null" , typeorm still setting value "DEFAULT" for undefined/null values.